# Understanding Test and Compile Dependencies of third party libs

Tags: java, maven, gradle, dependencies

In the [RabbitMQClient](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.rabbitmq/amqp-client/3.6.6) Project I can see that there are no compile dependencies but test dependencies.
But there are no testclasses inside the jar. And if I write test for my project which contains RabbitMQClient classes, I will only add dependencies to additional libs if I need them in my tests.
So whats the reason for the definition of test dependencies of such a external lib?
Maybe the answer is really easy, but I do not get it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test dependencies are used in the testing *of that project*. The entire idea is that they aren't needed as part of your project that uses it. (Of course, you might independently want some of the same libraries for your own tests because they're useful, but unlike compile-time dependencies, they aren't required in order to use the other project.)

Comment: Ok. So my understanding was correct, thats not relevant for me only if I try to checkout the whole RabbitMqClient project and execute the test. Thank you